# Pricing for Firestore when using StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

When using `StreamBuilder` in Flutter to read changes in a document in Firestore, how am I charged?

Am I charged for each time I listen whether there is any change or not multiplied by number of users or any different pricing is used.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After doing some research and reading documentation, I am ready to answer my own question.

If we are using `StreamBuilder` to fetch `Snapshot` from **Firestore** then we are charged for read **only when the data is updated** and are **NOT charged continuously**.

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: If we can't fetch exactly what we want when we want, it would be better to read only the documents exactly through streambuilder than to read a certain range of documents irresponsibly every time.